# Implement interface for all types implementing another interface C#

Tags: c#, .net, traits

Is it possible to implement an interface for all types implementing another interface in C#? For example,

```
interface A {
    void foo();
}

interface B {
    void bar();
}
```

Now I want to provide an implementation of `B` for all types which implement `A`. Is this possible? What I want is that any type `C:A` will also automatically be considered an implementer of `B`, i.e. `C:B`.

For example this is called 'impl trait for trait' in Rust. https://users.rust-lang.org/t/implementing-trait-for-trait/13810

Comment: _"want to provide an implementation of `B`"_ - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Doing `interface A : B {}` (so every `A` is also a `B`) which is one solution to my interpretation of your post.

Comment: ...or `interface A { B ExposedB { get; } }` - so that every `A` makes a `B` available (but the returned `B` does not necessarily share _object identity_ with `A` - which may-or-may-not-be desirable).

Answer (score 2):

Traits are not directly supported in C# (at least in my understanding of the topic) but you can somewhat simulate it with [default interface methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods). In this case you can utilize the [explicit default interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#explicit-implementation-in-interfaces) which will solve the problem to some extent:

```
interface IA : IB {
    void Foo();
    void IB.Bar() => Console.WriteLine("B implemented in A");
}

interface IB {
    void Bar();
}

class MyAWithB : IA
{
    public void Foo()
    {       
    }
}
```

And usage will require cast to `IA` or `IB`:

```
var myAWithB = new MyAWithB();
// myAWithB.Bar() // will not compile
(myAWithB as IA).Bar(); // prints B implemented in A
(myAWithB as IB).Bar(); // prints B implemented in A
```

P.S.

Personally I'm not a big fan of this feature and try not to introduce it in my codebases but arguably it can have some uses.

Also there are some interesting discussions to follow @github somewhat related to the topic:

- [Exploration: Roles, extension interfaces and static interface members](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/5498)
- [[Proposal]: Roles and extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/5496)